# In the building tool `parcelJs` how to export to global

Tags: javascript, build, parcel, parceljs

In `Webpack` there is a way to config all `export` parts on the entery file as a gloabl object, like you expect from lib (moment.js or jQuery for example )

But is look like the new building tool `parcel` can't do that. as far asI can read in the documention . but i proberayly miss somthing beause it seem to me as basic feature.

so *how make all `export` on the entry file as a object on the global*?

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, you should `import` everything.

Comment: so how can I design a lib ? or more simple use case how can I call API from `index.html` ?

Comment: Large-scale applications (that use a bundler) should not have code in `index.html`.  You should put all of your code in small, self-contained modules.  There are many blog posts about this.

Comment: Right but for Large-scale application i will use  `Webpack` I want to use `parcel` for simple projects.  or design code  in `web component` way. meen : mix of js + css +html together

Comment: If anyone is wondering how to set global variables for traditional JS and just using parcel to transpile/minify...then check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69511895/4484799

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting the browser simply attach the variable to `window` . Ex: `window.MyPlugin = require('my-plugin.js')`. When the bundle is imported in the browser `MyPlugin` will be available as a global.